Force Dark Mode in an iframe, regardless of user light or dark mode
Is it possible to use an <iframe> to display another website in my site, but want to display the dark mode version of that website, even if the user is using light mode?


<iframe
  height="610"
  src="https://www.are.na/gemma-copeland/internet-explorers/embed"
  style="filter: invert(1);"
  title="Gemma Copeland’s Are.na channel “Internet Explorers”"
  width="100%"
>
</iframe>



The invert filter didn't work as it inverted all the colours and then in the dark mode, it inverted it back to white.
